# Configuring wildfly standalone.xml for logging

Tags: xml, openshift, wildfly

I am trying to configure wildfly standalone.xml for logging I have configured other file in the standalone.xml logging is not done in the myapplication.log file. here is my configuration file.

```
         <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="1COMM" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="1COMM-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log" path="myapplication.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

there is no such file called myapplication.log in wildfly/logs
help needed to set a path? properly.

Comment: I got it working, actually i set the markers to hot_deploy so any changes in cartridges were not updating, as soon as restarted the app, changes applied ;)

Comment: Was the server running while you were changing the XML?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="myapplication.log"/>`.